# Split string in dataframe to json array in R

Tags: arrays, json, r

I need to export json from **dataframe** in R (use jsonlite). Everything's OK, except one thing. I have column with string in cells like this:

```
"one,two,three"
```

So after:

```
sink("out.json")
cat(toJSON(DF, pretty = TRUE))
sink()
```

Json looks:

```
{..."data" : "one,two,three"...}
```

I want array:

```
{..."data" : ["one","two","three"]...}
```

I tried strsplit to overwrite cell and replace value of cell with json, but it's not working.

```
strsplit:
==================
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 16, 5, value = list(c("one",  :
replacement element 1 has 3 rows to replace 1 rows

strplit and toJSON for cell:
==================
[1] "[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]"
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mutate the column to be a list rather than a character vector.

```
library('jsonlite')
library('tidyverse')

df <- tribble(
  ~column1, ~data,
  1,        'one,two,three',
  2,        'four,five'
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(data = stringr::str_split(data, ','))

toJSON(df, pretty = T)
# [
#   {
#     "a": 1,
#     "data": ["one", "two", "three"]
#   },
#   {
#     "a": 2,
#     "data": ["four", "five"]
#   }
# ]
```

Comment: I don't understand "tribble" from "tidyverse" (too large package), but i understood your message. Thanks. For me work this: `df$data <- as.list(strsplit(df$data, ","))`